# MySQL help merging two queries

Tags: mysql

I know this is simple but I can't figure it out.  Can you show me how to merge these two, so `Total` is to right of `Count`.

```
MariaDB [meta]> select `Sector`, count(*) as `Count` from meta where `Close` > `VWAP` and `Sector` != '' group by `Sector`;                                                                  +-----------------------+-------+
| Sector                | Count |
+-----------------------+-------+
| Basic Industries      |    85 |
| Capital Goods         |    90 |
| Consumer Durables     |    42 |
| Consumer Non-Durables |    63 |
| Consumer Services     |   237 |
| Energy                |    80 |
| Finance               |   233 |
| Health Care           |   165 |
| Miscellaneous         |    31 |
| Public Utilities      |   100 |
| Technology            |   162 |
| Transportation        |    35 |
+-----------------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [meta]> select `Sector`,count(`Sector`) as `Total` from `meta` where `Sector` != '' group by `Sector`;                                                                               +-----------------------+-------+
| Sector                | Total |
+-----------------------+-------+
| Basic Industries      |   368 |
| Capital Goods         |   403 |
| Consumer Durables     |   157 |
| Consumer Non-Durables |   237 |
| Consumer Services     |   832 |
| Energy                |   382 |
| Finance               |   880 |
| Health Care           |   681 |
| Miscellaneous         |   155 |
| Public Utilities      |   264 |
| Technology            |   709 |
| Transportation        |   114 |
+-----------------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also need another column for `Percentage` where count is a percentage of total.

Comment: Have you tried researching how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried subqueries and joins but I cannot figure out the proper context.  My issue is because of the GROUP BY, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `SELECT` clause to the second query:

```
SUM(`Close` > `VWAP`) AS `Count`
```

What it does is summarizes number of rows that have the `Close > VWAP` condition true.

The ANSII SQL-friendly (apart of using backticks) one would be

```
SUM(CASE WHEN `Close` > `VWAP` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Count`
```